# conditional product in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have a list which controls what terms in the data list have to be multiplied

```
control_list = [1, 0, 1, 1, 0]
data_list = [5, 4, 5, 5, 4]
```

I need to find product of elements in the `data_list` for which the `control_list` has `1`. My current attempt is naive and looks ugly!

```
product = 1
for i in range(len(control_list)):
    if control_list[i]: 
        product *= data_list[i]
```

I looked at `numpy.where()` to get the required elements in `data_list` but it looks like I did not get it right:

```
numpy.where(control_list, data_list)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-1534a6838544> in <module>()
----> 1 numpy.where(control_list, data_list)

ValueError: either both or neither of x and y should be given
```

My question is, can I do this somehow using numpy more efficiently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
control_list = numpy.array([1, 0, 1, 1, 0])
data_list = numpy.array([5, 4, 5, 5, 4])
numpy.product(data_list[control_list==1])
```

should do it ... it just says do product on datalist anywhere where `control_list == 1`

Comment: gee! it didn't occur to me it was this simple! thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

Try this out.  You can convert control_list to a list of booleans, and then use it to index into data_list.  Then, you can use numpy's product function to get the product of all of the values.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> cList = np.array(control_list, dtype=np.bool)
>>> cList
array([ True, False,  True,  True, False], dtype=bool)
>>> data_list = np.array(data_list)
>>> data_list[cList] # numpy supports fancy indexing
array([5, 5, 5])
>>> np.product(data_list[cList])
125
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, first, these should be arrays:

```
control = np.array([1, 0, 1, 1, 0])
data = np.array([5, 4, 5, 5, 4])
```

Now, we can convert `control` to a boolean mask:

```
control.astype(bool)
```

Select the corresponding elements of `data` with [advanced indexing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing):

```
data[control.astype(bool)]
```

And multiply those elements together with [`np.prod`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.prod.html):

```
product = np.prod(data[control.astype(bool)])
```